# __utm.gif is send but no output in the console from ga_debug.js

Tags: google-analytics

I can see the request in the network tab and the response is 200. But for some reason, ga_debug.js is not outputting anything to the console ("all" is selected).

Anyone else experienced this behaviour as well?

Comment: Have you tried using [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en)? Are you seeing tracking beacon? Any debug code?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Google Analytics Debugger. Not seeing the beacon send message, nor any other output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone disabled logging on production.

```
console.debug = $.noop;
console.log = $.noop;
console.info = $.noop;
console.warn = $.noop;
console.error = function(){
   // throw new Error(JSON.stringify(arguments));
};
```

Fix:

```
delete console.log
```

All good now